# Removing keys and values from a list of strings

Tags: python

Edit: Sorry for misleading you all, I make amendment to the data. That's what the data looks like after loading it with pandas.

thanks for always helping out. I have a list of strings like this:

```
    Index                 Data
     0           "[{"name": "bob", "age":"11", "id":"94884-0abdvnd-90", "participantid":"Me", "sentiment":"NEUTRAL", "content":"Hey, how you doing."}]" 

     1           "[{"name": "Roland", "age":"16", "id":"94884-0abdvnd-90", "participantid":"boy", "sentiment":"NEUTRAL", "content":"Hey, I'm doing good and you?."}]"]
```

And my goal is to remove certain keys and values so I only have the content left. That is:

```
     Index                 Data
     0           "[{"content":"Hey, how you doing."}]" 

     1           "[{"content":"Hey, I'm doing good and you?."}]"]
```

My initial approach was to convert each string to list using eval, then loop over it, but that only works for one string at a time. i.e I can only eval on mylist[0] then mylist[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2bO4.png) manually.

Here is the screenshot of the data:
[image]

Here is the sample of my code:

```
import ast
x = ast.literal_eval(mylist)
keys_to_keep = ["content"]
new_list = [{ key: item[key] for key in keys_to_keep } for item in x]
```

The above code will bring an error except I use x[0], x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2bO4.png) etc. Is there any better way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't syntactically valid, can you please re-visit the quotes here?

Comment: Looks like JSON; have you tried using a JSON parser for this?

Comment: It's actually a csv file. I converted it to list so I can easily manipulate it that way.

Comment: Either you've completely misunderstood your file contents, or your CSV is utterly broken. (Possibly both.)

Comment: Well, I load the csv file using pandas, and that gives me two columns: the index column and the the data column. The data column each looks like this:  0: "[{"name": "bob", "age":"11", "id":"94884-0abdvnd-90", "participantid":"Me", "sentiment":"NEUTRAL", "content":"Hey, how you doing."}]"                            1 : "[{"name": "Roland", "age":"16", "id":"94884-0abdvnd-90", "participantid":"boy", "sentiment":"NEUTRAL", "content":"Hey, I'm doing good and you?."}]"

Comment: And my goal is to remove everything else except from the content.

Comment: I make edit to what the data really looks like

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json` module of Python standard library here - it is safer than using `eval` on the inputs which might contain code to pretty much anything.

E.g. like this (assuming `mylist` is a list of strings each of which is a valid json with one-element list):

```
import json
keys_to_keep = ["content"]
new_list = []
for x in mylist:
    item = json.loads(x)
    new_list.append({ key: item[key] for key in keys_to_keep})
```

Comment: So string_value in this case is my list of strings right?

Comment: You can apply it in the loop as well. The string literal in your question is very clearly not the actual way you create `mylist` cause it doesn't escape symbols `"`  inside double-quote string.

Comment: The `my_list` declaration in your current version of the question is not a valid Python code, so I don't know what is the data you really have in your `my_list` variable.

Comment: In your example every line has a list with exactly one element - is that always the case? If not what do you want to get in the end if e.g. first line has 4 elements and second 7 elements. Do you want to get one list with 11 elements or a list of lists with first one having 7 elements and second one having 4?

Comment: From what I listed above, the data column has a list quoted in a string, and inside that list there is a dictionary. What I need exactly is to delete keys in the dictionary except the content key I want to leave behind. So in the end, I just want to have the content key alone and every other thing deleted.

Comment: Ok, I'm still not sure what is the answer for the last question I asked, but let me update my answer for the case which is assuming you always have 1 element list on every line.